# Server 2003 Proxy Policy

Tags: windows-server-2003, proxy, group-policy

I'm working on a small Windows Server 2003 domain that has a policy set on a single OU to apply proxy settings. At the time that this policy was created, it was reported to be working just fine.

Currently the machines in that OU are not getting the proper proxy settings. A different IP address is appearing as the proxy server in Internet Options on all of these machines, but they are also set to not use the proxy. The really weird thing is that if I change the proxy address manually on one of these machines, it reverts back to the incorrect settings.

All other policies are applying just fine, and I can't find any policy with conflicting proxy settings. Does anybody out there have any ideas? Is there some other place that I can look for a potential conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resultant Set of Policy is your friend. If you haven't used it yet, use it.

Logon to a PC having the problem as a user experiencing the problem.

- Start / Run / MMC
- File / Add/Remove Snap-in / Add / Resultant Set of Policy / Add / Close / OK
- Right-click Resultant Set of Policy / Generate RSoP Data...
- Click "Next" until you get to "Finish".

Look thru the "Proxy Settings" under the "Connection" settings, under the "Internet Explorer Maintenance" settings, under the "Windows Settings", under the "User Settings" node. The "Precedence" tab should show you any GPO's with this setting specified.

Since you see it "refreshing" I would guess that it's an erroneously-applied GPO.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I already ran RSoP and found no other policies that were applying proxy settings. I got really excited a bit ago when I saw this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825685 but the policy isn't in preference mode either.

Comment: Alright... RSoP did show that the correct policy was winning, but I guess there was another policy with proxy settings specified. I got rid of those settings, but then for some reason the correct policy still wouldn't apply. I gave the proxy policy higher priority and now it's working. I'm not sure why I didn't do that to begin with. ;)

Comment: Ah, ha-- my psychic powers prevail again! I don't trust the visual display of the whole "priority" nonsense. I learned the algorithm that Group Policy uses to apply GPOs years ago (W2K times) and I still use that, to this day, to diagnose GPO application issues. RSoP has probably made me a little "soft", but walking the directory tree "by hand" and building the list of GPOs that apply to a given computer/user object still can't be beat.